WooCommerce Cart Notices
How can I change the CONTINUE SHOPPING text?
I tryed this snipped, but didn't work for me:
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'quadlayers_custom_add_to_cart_message' ); function quadlayers_custom_add_to_cart_message() { $message = 'Your product has been added to cart. Thank you for shopping with us!' ; return $message; }
PRODUCT (TEST): https://paratyyogafestival.com.br/2024/ingressos/workshop-teste/
I also would like to change the order from button with the message:
PRINT SCREEN
Thanks in advance.

You should try to set priority when using the filter.
In the function you should use the parameters, check if the string is existent and replace it if it is.
Make sure to put this code inside of your functions.php or a custom plugin.
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'quadlayers_custom_add_to_cart_message', 10, 2 );

function quadlayers_custom_add_to_cart_message($message, $products){

    if (strpos($message, "Continue shopping") !== false) {
        $message = str_replace("Continue shopping", "Your custom Message", $message);
    }

    return $message;

}


Hi, thanks for your reply. It didin't work as well =/
